# web site is redircting to wrong url hosted in locally

Tags: asp.net, localhost, web-hosting

I was having the following issue with the web site I hosted on `http://localhost/` which was previously hosted on visual studio. I have created folder name website4 in the rool folder and move the website.

Then I got following error.

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The virtual path '/assets/masters/homepage.master' maps to another application, which is not allowed.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="/assets/masters/homepage.master" Title="Content Page 1" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Extra_dNet_Code" Runat="Server">

Source File: /WebSite4/default.aspx    Line: 1
```

Then I changed the above url ('/assets/masters/homepage.master') to following ('~/assets/masters/homepage.master').
After that I got the following error

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The virtual path '/assets/stylesheets/css.ascx' maps to another application, which is not allowed.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Master Language="C#" %>
Line 2:  <%@ Register Src="/assets/stylesheets/css.ascx" TagName="css" TagPrefix="include" %>
Line 3:  <%@ Register Src="/assets/javascripts/scripts.ascx" TagName="scripts" TagPrefix="include" %>
Line 4:  <%@ Register Src="/assets/header/header.ascx" TagName="header" TagPrefix="include" %>

Source File: /WebSite4/assets/masters/homepage.master    Line: 2
```

Then I changed the above url to following

```
<%@ Register Src="~/assets/stylesheets/css.ascx" TagName="css" TagPrefix="include" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/assets/javascripts/scripts.ascx" TagName="scripts" TagPrefix="include" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/assets/header/header.ascx" TagName="header" TagPrefix="include" %>
```

However it started to work the site without javascript and css.
When I click images it always redirect the site following urls without website4. Somthing similar like this url

```
`http://localhost/assets/images/...`
```

Above link should be

`http://localhost/website4/assets/images/...`

Or it just redirect to `http://localhost.`

How to fix that issue?

Answer (score 0):

try specifying your `MasterPage` relative url like below:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/assets/masters/homepage.master"  .. %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/assets/masters/homepage.master" %>
```

Note that, when you do `~/`, asp.net will look for `root/assets/masters/homepage.master`

do not use just the forward slash, use it with ~ i.e. `~/`

Comment: I have mentioned that I tried about. Is there anyconfiguation to specify the base url in asp.net?

Comment: No, there has to be something wrong with your solution then, may be duplicate names

Comment: I am new to asp.net could you explain this. How to fix that?

Comment: so tell me this, your project was working when you launched it through Visual Studio? And not when you hosted it in IIS?

Comment: so, first of all, verify that, your IIS supports that version of DOT.NET, in which your Project is built, you should better search on how to host ASP.NET site in IIS (its simple btw), besides, do note that include your css and js files the way you would in an html file, and just do this, `<script src='<% ResolveUrl("~/relative path to js file") %/>' />`